# calculating principal and interest and amount remaining

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Loan Infor]

Loan Details excel:

```
D1: Loan Amount: 4000
D2: Loan Term (months): 24
D3: Repayment Frequency: fortnightly
D4: Repayment Amount: 93.29
D5: Annual Interest Rate: 12%
```

```
 in excel table header
G1: account_number
H1: repayment_date
I1: repayment_amount
J1: amount_remaining
K1: Principal
L1: Interest
```

| account number | repayment date | repayment amount | amount remaining | Principal | Interest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1-Jun-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 15-Jun-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 29-Jun-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 13-Jul-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 27-Jul-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 10-Aug-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 24-Aug-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 7-Sep-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 21-Sep-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 5-Oct-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 19-Oct-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 2-Nov-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 16-Nov-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 30-Nov-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 14-Dec-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 28-Dec-22 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 11-Jan-23 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 25-Jan-23 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 8-Feb-23 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 22-Feb-23 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 8-Mar-23 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 22-Mar-23 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 5-Apr-23 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 19-Apr-23 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 3-May-23 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 17-May-23 | 93.29 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 31-May-23 | 93.29 |  |  |  |

what i need to calculate is the amount remaining and pricipal and interest for each repayment date
in excel i have tried a few things but it doesnt work note the repayment amount should not change
please if someone can help me calculate i tried getting some information

```
    K2 (Principal): =PPMT(D5/24,ROW()-1,D2,-D1)
    L2 (Interest): =IPMT(D5/24,ROW()-1,D2,-D1)
    J2 (Remaining Amount):
```

but this does not work for me
when i try to use this formula =PPMT(D5/24,ROW()-1,D2,-D1) it gives me an error saying something is wrong in the formula.

Comment: Why is rate (2nd argument) based on the row position? Have you checked the detail of the ppmt() funct5ion or the examples?

Comment: @SolarMike sorry i am not too sure on how it should work

Comment: I'm unclear: You have the term (in months) as 24 (ie 2 years), but the payments are fortnightly? You would need 52 payments (=365 * 2 / 14, give or take a few days). And where does the fixed payment of 93.29 come from (fwiw I see the payment as 86.27)?

Comment: @DS_London
hi yes that is correct , for some reason in our system the repayment is 93.29 every fortnightly, for 24months (2 years) , we are trying to move to a new system so the challenge is that the new system needs a breakdown for interest and principal but our system does not have that, without changing the repayment amount i am trying to calculate the P & I of the repayment amount.

Comment: Since you already have the payment schedule, you don't need PPMT or IPMT (these are used to calculate the payments on an amortizing loan). So it is just an iterative calculation: for each period you need the principal outstanding at the start of the period (for the 1st payment, the OS is 4k). The interest payment is this principal * interest rate (annual rate / 26). The principal payment is the fixed payment less the interest payment.

Comment: i dont really understand

Comment: Look at [this site](https://www.howtogeek.com/816269/amortization-schedule-excel/) on amortization schedules using Excel, with links to spreadsheets that do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PeterT i just have my schedule and fixed repayment value what i want is to calculate the principal and interest amount  repayment amount which needs to end up to my repayment amount.

Comment: All of the Excel formulas to calculate loan amortization generally calculate your payment amount, instead of taking your payment amount. I recommend visiting [this site](https://www.exceldemy.com/biweekly-mortgage-calculator-with-extra-payments-excel/) and downloading the template to dig into the formula. You can determine how to get your principal and interest from that or perhaps rework your data to fit the existing formulas.

Answer (score 1):

So it bugged me enough to work it out.

The Loan Details work out to:

[image]

Where the Bi-weekly interest rate is `=$D$5/$D$2` (=IntRate/LoanTerm)

Then, the table itself works out to:

[image]

With the formulas, copied down the column:

- in Column J, starting in J4:  `=J3-I4`
- in Column K, starting in K4:  `=I4-L4`
- in Column L, starting in L4:  `=J3*$D$7`